# How do I rename a homebrew tap

Tags: homebrew

I have tapped something as a certain name, but now I want to change the name. How do I do that in homebrew?

Today:

```sh
$ brew tap
[...]
existing/tap-name
```

Desired:

```sh
$ brew tap
[...]
new/tap-name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Homebrew doesn't (AFAICT) store information about what taps are installed anywhere on the filesystem, so all you need to do is move the directory to the correct new location.

This is made easier as `brew --repo my-tap/name` will tell you where a tap should go even if the tap doesn't yet exist.

```sh
old_tap=existing/tap-name # What you currently see in `brew tap`.
new_tap=new/tap-name # What you want to see in `brew tap`.

old_path=$(brew --repo "${old_tap?}")
new_path="$(brew --repo "${new_tap?}")"
mkdir -p "$(dirname "${new_path?}")"
mv "${old_path?}" "${new_path?}"
```